# SPFX - PnP JS Core for SPFx On-Premise v1.0.2

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, spfx, spfx-webparts, pnp-js-core

I want to use PnP JS Core in  SPFx **v1.0.2** React webpart for SP16 On-premise server .

- What is the version of pnp need to use and how to install it?
- What are the other options for accessing data in SP with this
  version(1.0.2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SPFx for SharePoint 2016 currently uses `Typescript 2.1.x`.

The pnp compatible version for that is **version 2.0.8**. The latest version **3.0.0** throws some errors because of some breaking changes.

To install that, you need to run the below command:

```
npm install sp-pnp-js@2.0.8 --save
```

**Update**  - the latest version 3.0.x works just fine, just that you need to setup the library as below:

```
pnp.setup({
    sp: {
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        }
    }
});
```

To install it, just need to run the below command:

```
npm install sp-pnp-js@latest --save
```

Reference - [Moving from PnP JS core 2.0.x to 3.0.x](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Moving-from-2.0.*-to-3.0.*)

[PnP JS core configuration](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Configuration)

The alternate to that is to use the `sphttpclient` to perform CRUD operations.

You can find an excellent example [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/dev/samples/sharepoint-crud). Check the noFramework webpart.

Comment: working with new version of pnp-core-js --> 3.0.1